# Setup SSL under Meteor with npm package http-proxy

Tags: node.js, ssl, meteor, https, proxy

I'm trying to setup SSL with Meteor using [SSL - Meteorpedia](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/SSL). I have installed meteorhacks:npm and defined the current version of the [npm http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) package in the pakcages.json file. Now i've setup in server folder the following meteor-method:

```
Meteor.methods({
'ssl': function(options) {
  var fs, httpProxy, proxy;
  httpProxy = Meteor.npmRequire('http-proxy');
  proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer(options);
  fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs');
  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    return proxy.web(req, res, {
      target: "http://" + this.connection.httpHeaders.host + "3000"
    });
  });
  proxy.on('error', function(e) {
    if (DEV_MODE) {
      return console.log(e);
    } else {
      return document.body = "The request couldn't be handled";
    }
  });
  return http.listen(443);
}
```

});

I was trying to call this in my main client javascript file but when calling https://localhost:3000 the connection is refused:

```
Meteor.call('ssl', {
 secure: true,
 ssl: {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/ssl/server.key.pem', 'utf8')
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/ssl/server.cert.pem', 'utf8')
 },
 target: {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 443
 }
})
```

The server.cert.pem and server.key.pem file are in private/ssl folder. Unfortunately i don't know where i need to set which host/domain/port. Meteor runs on standard port 3000 on localhost (development environment) and Nginx has the following SSL setting:

```
# HTTPS server

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl_certificate      server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  server.key;

    #ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```